# How to Stop NodeJS process gracefully from npm script

Tags: node.js, express, npm, package.json

I've a scenario to run **cypress E2E** test and for which , I need **NodeJS** application to be up. So, I'm using `wait-on` library and i'm able to run the **cypress E2E** test but it leaves my **NodeJS** application running in background.

I want to end the **NodeJS** process running in background as part of my `cypress:e2e`  npm script.

---

***Question***:  How can I send **SIGINT** signal from npm script because in my **server.ts**, I'm exiting the process with **SIGINT**. **(no ctrl+c would help)**

---

**server.ts :**

```
/****************************/
/* Start Up The Node Server */
/****************************/
APP.listen(PORT, () => {
  logger.info(
    `Node application has started their node server on port ${PORT}`,
  )
})

process.on('SIGINT', () => process.exit(1))
```

**npm scripts:**

```
{
    "start": "node dist/server",
    "test:e2e": "ng e2e",
    "stop": ""
    "cypress:e2e": "npm run start & wait-on http://localhost:8080 && npm run test:e2e && npm run stop"
}
```

Please help to write npm script **"stop"**.

Better solutions or approaches would be appreciated.

---

**Solutions tried:**

```
"stop": "kill -SIGINT %1"
```

I still have the process running :

[image]

Comment: You have the PID in `%1` so you can use `kill -SIGINT %1` (or `kill $(jobs -p)`), but only inside the same subshell so it wouldn't work with a separate `stop` script unless you pass it in as argument. Alternatively use a pidfile.

Comment: Is there anything which can be done - without using PID?

Comment: Without PID, how would you identify your process? Other approaches like command line would be a lot more complicated and fragile as well. (you could use a unique `process.title` but again it's already more complicated than necessary)

Comment: @CherryDT  I just tried **kill -SIGINT %1** but it didn't help . Updated the result in question.

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment: `[...] but only inside the same subshell so it wouldn't work with a separate "stop" script unless you pass it in as argument.` - You put it as `stop` script so it doesn't work, as mentioned. Either make it part of the `cypress:e2e` script (instead of `npm run stop`) or pass the PID as argument from `cypress:e2e` to `stop` and refer to the argument in the `stop` script. (The `%1` variable - or the output of the `jobs` builtin, for that matter - refers to the jobs created by the same shell using `&` - it won't magically refer to the parent shell's jobs)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this.

#### Use `pkill`:

```sh
pkill -SIGINT -f server.ts
```

This way, you do not need to know the PID of the process. However, this will send a signal to **all processes** that have "server.ts" in the command line.

#### Use a *pidfile*

In `server.ts`, write `process.pid` to a pidfile, for example `server.pid`. Then use the pidfile to send a signal.

```sh
pkill -SIGINT --pidfile server.pid
```

This can also be done from Node.js with `process.kill()`.

You should remove the pidfile when the server process exits.

#### Use an endpoint

In `server.ts` add a route to shutdown the server.

```js
app.post('/shutdown', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
  process.exit(0);
});
```

Then send a request to this endpoint at the end of the e2e tests or from the command line with `curl`.

You should probably only enable this endpoint in development and not in production.